# Clipping rotated rectangle in Silverlight XAML

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I am trying to clip a rotated rectangle, in a similar fashion to the way I can clip a scaled rectangle. Here's some simple code:

```
<Canvas>
  <!--first example: clipping (transparent yellow) correctly clips scaled rectangle -->
  <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="200" Height="200" Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="20">
    <Rectangle.Clip>
      <RectangleGeometry Rect="0, 0, 200, 100">
        <RectangleGeometry.Transform>
          <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5"/>
        </RectangleGeometry.Transform> 
      </RectangleGeometry>
    </Rectangle.Clip>
    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
      <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2"/>
    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
  </Rectangle>
  <Rectangle Width="200" Height="100" Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="20">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
      <SolidColorBrush Color="Yellow" Opacity="0.5"/>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
  </Rectangle>
  <!--second example: clipping (transparent yellow) incorrectly clips rotated rectangle -->
  <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="200" Height="200" Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="250">
    <Rectangle.Clip>
      <RectangleGeometry Rect="0, 0, 200, 100">
        <RectangleGeometry.Transform>
          <RotateTransform CenterX="100" CenterY="100" Angle="0"/>
        </RectangleGeometry.Transform>
      </RectangleGeometry>
    </Rectangle.Clip>
    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
      <RotateTransform CenterX="100" CenterY="100" Angle="45"/>
    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>   
  </Rectangle>
  <Rectangle Width="200" Height="100" Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="250">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
      <SolidColorBrush Color="Yellow" Opacity="0.5"/>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
      <RotateTransform CenterX="100" CenterY="100" Angle="0"/>
    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
  </Rectangle>
</Canvas>
```

In the first example I can clip the scaled (expanded) rectangle by scaling (shrinking) the clipping area. In the second example I'd like to do something similar - keep the clipping area represented by the yellow rectangle by somehow manipulating the Transform object of the clip of the red rectangle. This shouldn't be difficult, but I can't see it. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Am I the only one a little confused as to what's being asked here? What's the end effect you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to clip a rotated rectangle, in a similar fashion to the way I can clip a scaled rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
<Grid Background="Yellow" Canvas.Left="400" Canvas.Top="50" ClipToBounds="True" Width="200" Height="100">
    <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="200" Height="200">
        <Rectangle.Clip>
            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0, 0, 200, 100">
                <RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                    <RotateTransform CenterX="100" CenterY="100" Angle="0"/>
                </RectangleGeometry.Transform>
            </RectangleGeometry>
        </Rectangle.Clip>
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform CenterX="100" CenterY="100" Angle="45"/>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>   
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

Will give you this:

[image: Clipped rectangle in a grid]

[The red rectangle is the same as from your example, just removed `Canvas.Top`/`Canvas.Left` setters]

Is that what you were looking for?

## EDIT:

Sorry, didn't notice the Silverlight tag.

Try this:

```
<Grid Background="Yellow" Width="200" Height="100">
    <Grid.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0, 0, 200, 100"/>
    </Grid.Clip>
    <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="200" Height="200">
        <Rectangle.Clip>
            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0, 0, 200, 100">
                <RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                    <RotateTransform CenterX="100" CenterY="100" Angle="0"/>
                </RectangleGeometry.Transform>
            </RectangleGeometry>
        </Rectangle.Clip>
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform CenterX="100" CenterY="100" Angle="45"/>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>   
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

Same visual result in KaXaml.